# 4x4 matrix with 1's in the diagonals (like a cross) and 0's everywhere else, using python

Tags: python, numpy

i am able to get the checkerboard pattern, the + pattern and the one with 1's on the border but i am not able to figure this out. Can somebody help?

Comment: `np.eye(4) + np.fliplr(np.eye(4))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sticking with whole dimensions, then as [@Péter Leéh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11751294/p%C3%A9ter-le%C3%A9h) pointed out:

```
>>> np.eye(n) + np.fliplr(np.eye(n))
array([[1., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

will suffice, [`np.fliplr(x)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html#numpy.fliplr) (*horizontal flip*) is identical to [`np.flip(x, axis=1)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html).

However if `n` is odd, then you will have to replace the center element with a `1`. *e.g.* `n=5`:

```
>>> x = np.eye(n) + np.fliplr(np.eye(n))
>>> x[n//2, n//2] = 1
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

Comment: In case `n` is odd, I think it's easier: `1 * np.logical_or(np.eye(5), np.fliplr(np.eye(5)))`